# Error installing Firebase

Tags: ios, ssl, firebase, cocoapods

```
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/6f/wy97bnq96f30fl3qlgfmn0tc0000gn/T/d20160826-2616-gnrjr/file.tgz https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/cc5f7aac07ccdd0a/Firebase-3.5.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
```

this is an error when i install Firebase, Does someone who can help?

Comment: have you tried using sudo [command] to install it?

Comment: How? I don't know